# Problematic CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my sample app I am using material design widgets. A CoordinatorLayout,an AppBarLayout,a CollapsingToolbarLayout and a view pager that holds 3 tabs.

It looks like that.

[image: image1]

However when I scroll up,the layout doesn't look so good.

[image: image2]

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/orange"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"


        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ael"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="104dp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"


            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:gravity="top"


            />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e91111"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffd900"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffdd00"
    app:tabTextColor="#fff"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>



<!-- </FrameLayout>-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any ideas on my problem?

Thanks

Theo.

Comment: can you post your style.xml that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change Toolbar heigh attribute.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:gravity="top"
        />
```